# Subsetting with multple rows in R?

Tags: r, subset

I've been trying to figure out how to set multiple conditions for a subset.
I have successfully created subsets with one condition or even multiple continuous variables but I can't seem to understand how to collect multiple conditions in a single subset. Below is what I believed should have been the correct way, but once I go beyond the first column set ("CA") it starts having issues. It doesn't have an error when ran but the dimension comes back at 17 columns with 0 rows. For more context, the dataset includes rows of different earthquake events, with State being a column I'm trying to reduce to only show California, Alaska, and Hawaii. I hope this explains my issue, I'm pretty new to this and may not be asking in the correct way. I've looked through previously asked questions similar to mine but they haven't made much sense to me.

EQus = subset(EQ, State == "CA" | State == "AK" | State == "HI")

I've tried other variations of the code above with no help, such as changing the or (|) to an and (&) but still nothing.

Comment: Try using ```filter()``` from the dplyr package, which takes in conditional arguments. You may input multiple conditional statements separated by the "&" operator.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: The use of `dplyr::filter` should change nothing from the `subset(.)` code given above, so I don't know that it is any better. Lacking an sample data, I would have to guess that the `State` column is not like you expect: it might be a different case, or it might have spaces in or around the state abbreviation letters.

Comment: Your code works fine on this data frame: `EQ <- data.frame(State=sample(state.abb, 200, replace=TRUE))` so there must be some other issue that we cannot diagnose without your data or a sample of it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, without a subset of the data it is impossible to precisely identify what the issues may be. However, if you are looking for a subset which can match one of multiple character options, may I suggest `%in%` as in:

```r
EQus <-  subset(EQ, State %in% c(CA", "AK", "HI"))
```

For example:

```r
set.seed(62L)
n <- 25L
EQ <- data.frame(State = sample(state.abb, n, TRUE),
                 Strength = round(runif(n, 0, 5), 1L))
EQ
   State Strength
1     NV      0.8
2     MI      3.0
3     TX      2.4
4     CA      2.4
5     WA      4.3
6     CA      2.1
7     NJ      3.7
8     NH      1.8
9     WA      4.4
10    MD      1.7
11    AR      2.3
12    KY      4.7
13    CT      0.4
14    NH      2.6
15    IL      4.2
16    ND      1.4
17    CT      4.0
18    MD      4.1
19    CO      4.5
20    NC      0.9
21    MI      1.3
22    VT      0.9
23    AK      2.5
24    MA      4.5
25    OH      0.1

EQus <- subset(EQ, State %in% c("CA", "AK", "HI"))
EQus
   State Strength
4     CA      2.4
6     CA      2.1
23    AK      2.5
```